# bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-10.04

i am working on Ubuntu10.10 OS and i have downloaded  eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz. my computer is 64 bit machine.

when i untar eclipse and try run `./eclipse` from command line, it gives me above error.

when i run `file eclipse` , it gives me following information.

```
 eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses
 shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

Could someone help me to find out what is going wrong here

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you checked if that Linux installation is 64bit? While your processor may support 64bit mode, you may be running a 32bit OS. Check with uname -a. If you see something like i686 or i386 and not ia64 or x86_64 then you are running a 32bit system and cannot run 64bit binaries.

Comment: yes, it is the problem , i downloaded 32 bit eclipse and, not it works fine. Thank you punnie

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My bet is that you are using a x86 Ubuntu with a x86_64 JVM. To make sure your Ubuntu is 64 bits, run the following command:

```
$ uname -i
```

Comment: Not the JVM but the eclipse launcher at least. But since this is not a rights issue then you are probably running a 32 bit kernel (even on a 64 bit machine).

Comment: it gave following output :::
Linux localhost 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:34:50 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
::::My ubuntu os is 32 bit :)
my java version is :::lib/<arch>/jvm.cfg (where <arch> is i386, amd64, sparc or sparcv9)

Comment: yup, your operating system is 32bit. either download the 32bit eclipse package or install a 64bit OS.

Comment: yes problem solved, my os is 32 bit and 32 bit eclipse works fine. thank you everyone for spending your valuable time on this issue.

Comment: @gabuzo That's weird... 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit OS? Why would that be the case?

Comment: @Shurane nope, 64 bit machine/server with a 32 bit OS/Kernel

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a right problem `chmod +x ./eclipse` should help and if it does not `ls -l eclipse`

Comment: hi gabuzeo, 
chmod +x ./eclipse didn't work, 
ls -l eclipse gave 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kapila kapila 71162 2010-08-10 20:48 eclipse

Comment: hi Tyler
this is seems to not working. it still give same message

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the 64-bit version of Eclipse - you need to download the **32**-bit one!