# Cannot run easyeclipse with error: No such file or directory

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, ubuntu

Shell cannot run executable file eclipse even if I enter proper path. the file is executable and readable.

Why bash cannot find the file?

I've also install java (openjdk-7-jre), and normal eclipse is running well

```
~/eclipse:

about_files    eclipse.ini      icon.xpm         notice.html
about.html     eclipse-wrapper  jre              plugins
configuration  epl-v10.html     libcairo-swt.so  readme
eclipse        features         LICENSE.TXT      startup.jar

$ ./eclipse
bash: ./eclipse: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I am not sure but you can have a look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65058/eclipses-executable-file-wont-run-in-ubuntu

Comment: and possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898508/bash-eclipse-cannot-execute-binary-file

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with 32 bit vs 64 bit.  If you download the wrong package for your architecture, you could end up with this message instead of a more informative message saying that you are running the wrong version of eclipse for your machine